# Issues with jdbc producer in streamsets

Tags: mysql, streamsets

I was trying migrating data from local directory to mysql db using Streamsets pipeline.While previewing data is on the console but not written to mysql db.The pipeline showing no error but still data is not written to db.If anyone worked on Streamsets kindly help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

By default, preview mode does not write data to the destination; in your case, MySQL. You can check the **Write to Destinations and Executors** option to make it do so, or just run the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Streamsets preview mode is just to see whether or not your pipeline is working fine or will work as expected. Please stop preview mode and start pipeline as run or start.